# Trying to list an NFT but it says insufficient funds

Tags: metamask, nft, polygon

I recently move ETH to Polygon so I can list an NFT for sale. However, it keeps saying I have insufficient funds when I try to list it. On my Metamask it's showing 0 ETH but theres a balance of ETH ERC20? Not sure if thats why OpenSea is thinking I don't have any funds in Polygon. Please help[image]

[image]

Comment: Probably you don't have MATIC

Comment: I have the same problem. Could it be that we need WETH instead of Eth?